# PreventDefault inside of promise in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, promise

I'm new to full stack development and I was looking for some pointers to how I can handle errors that return from a promise.

Basically, I have Game IDs stored in a MongoDB collection. When a user enters a Game ID, I want to check if the Game ID exists in the collection. If it doesn't, I don't want to link the user to a new page. If it does, the user should go to a new page.

Currently, my code doesn't prevent default and the user still goes to the "waitpage", even if I use event.preventDefault. I'm wondering how I can stop the user from going to this page.

This is the code I have right now in the frontend.

```
const onJoinGame = (event) => {
    event.persist()
    axios.get(`${BACKENDLINK}/rooms/${gameId}/room_available`)
        .then((res) => {
            if(res.data.Status == true){
                axios.put(`${BACKENDLINK}/rooms/${gameId}/add_user`,
                 {
                    username: username
                 })
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            setErrorGameId("That game doesn't exist!")
        })
}
```

And in the return statement, I use this function like so.

```
<Link to={`/${gameId}/waitpage`} onClick={(event) => onJoinGame(event)}>
    <button className = "submit" id="joinGame">Join Game</button>
</Link>
```

In the backend, this is what my get function returns.

```
const roomAvailable = (req, res) => {
Room.findOne({roomId: req.params.id}, (err, result) =>{
    if(!result){
        res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err) 
    }
    else{
        
        res.json({'Status': true})
    }
})
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the event from a promise, you'll need to do that synchronously in the event handler.

If you do need to navigate to the other page after all, you'll have to do that manually using the imperative API of the router package (which provides `Link`) you're using.